React Navigation Header Padding Issue on iOS – Extra Space at Top of Header in Stack and Tab Navigation
In React Native, I'm using the following dependencies:
"react-native": "^0.74.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.21"
"@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
"@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",

In both stack and tab navigation, when I set a header, it's creating a white space (like a paddingTop) at the top of the header bar. What could be wrong? Has anyone had a similar issue?


Could you please submit the source code so that we may inspect your code and assess your mistakes and provide you with a solution?

To render view in React Native for iOS, we use the SafeAreaView component.
SafeAreaView renders nested content and automatically applies padding to reflect the portion of the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views.

I know, I'm using it, but that spacing belongs to the header bar, if I use { headerShown: false } the header will disappear, and the contents get close to the top, without that space.
